# Keep android service from draining battery

Tags: android, sockets, service, android-service

DISCLAIMER: This is at once a system design question, since I am interested in alternative approaches; and a coding question, since I am looking for specific technique.

Say I have a server at ip `89.374.52.452` and port `7893`: so I am using **Socket**. I want to track/consumer every message that this server sends out using an android app. Tracking the server while the app is running is *simple enough. But **I want to track the server even when the app is not running? How do I do that?***

**Present Solution**

I am using a service to track the server. I start the service with `START_STICKY`. The problem I seem to be experiencing is that the service seems to be killing my battery. Is my assessment right? Is the very fact — in itself — of having a service running indefinitely killing my battery? Or is it something else? Is my approach good system design? Assuming I have no control over the server and so cannot have the server send notifications: is there another way to track activity on a server besides

```
 public class MyThread implements Runnable {        
    @Override    
    public void run() {
            try {    
            if(null == socket || !socket.isConnected() || socket.isClosed()){

                InetAddress theServer = InetAddress.getByName(server_IP); 
                socket = new Socket(theServer, serverIPPort);  }

             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    handlers.post(new Runnable() {    
                    public void run() {
                            if (line.length() > 0) {    
                            …//store line    
                        }
                        }    
                });
                }    
        } catch (Exception e) {    
            e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    if (null != socket) {
                        socket.close();
                        socket=null;    
                }
                } catch (IOException io) {    
                io.printStackTrace();
                }
            }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: It may be that the bg service placing so many calls. How frequently it calls the

Comment: what do you mean by "so many calls"? I keep the socket open. Are there calls being made that I am not aware of?

Comment: Calls to server. Http calls.

Comment: I get what you mean, so thanks. But to be exact, I am not using http abstraction: I am using sockets directly.